# Can't add a value into a vector nested inside of a map

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary

So I have created a nested template (a map of vectors) using stanford's CS106 C++ library—which I believe is created to follow regular comp-sci modus operandi.

```
Map<Vector<char> > mv;
```

I can't figure out the syntax for adding a key/value pair, where the value is of course a vector entry...
So far I've tried variations of this:

```
mv.put("key", 'A');
```

**Error** from the above code: No viable conversion from 'char' to 'Vector'

put() is the member function that adds a key/value pair.

The key is working fine. The problem is inserting the char into the a vector. I have no troubles adding a value to an already created key, it's just creating a new key with a value that I can't do.

add() is the member function for adding a char into the vector.

Totally unsure how the syntax is meant to look, I've tried searching for a solution with no luck, and my tinkering has been fruitless thus far.

Thanks for any help, much appreciated :)

**edit**: Sorry I should have included this from the start, here is the library documentation: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/cs106lib/

Comment: Map needs two type parameters.

Comment: No, it doesn't. This CS106 Map type always uses `string` as the key.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, what do you mean by two type parameters?

Comment: Oh yes, Ernest is correct, Map keys are always strings in CS106 Map, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How obscure. Why develop a less good library to replace something that's part of the standard already and will be more useful outside the classroom in every aspect?

Comment: No idea, I'm not versed well enough to know, but I suspect it would be a pedagogical reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Vector<char> v;
v.add('A');
mv.put("key", v);
```

Comment: Would that nest a Vector nested inside my Vector?

Comment: No. Until you use `put()`, there's no `Vector` for the given key. You have to put an actual vector in there. To add a value to the Vector when you already  know the key exists in the `Map`, you'd use `mv.get("key").add('B');`. But if you do this before the key has been added, it raises a runtime error.

Comment: Ah true! That makes sense :) Thanks Ernest! Working perfect now. This is why I love StackOverflow... 15 mins later and I have a solution. Great!